# Reflectors that reflect sunbeams to a certain point at any given time

Tags: geometric-optics, geometry

Let us say you live in a town at a latitude of around 50 degree North. The town doesn't get much, if any, sun, because there are hill ranges to the east, to the south, and to the west.
[image: map]

Inspired by similar projects, like the one in the picture below in Norway, you want to install reflecting structures on the hills in order to have sunlight reflected into your village, especially during the dark months.

[image: rjukan_norway]

Because you are a fan of simple mechanical solutions (you also love reaction ferries or waterweight powered funiculars), you want to reflect light into the town all (or most of) the time of the day (from any or least a substantial part of all possible angles of the sun), without having to install motors that rotate the mirrors. Is there a simple geometrical solution to this problem?

Related problem: Reflect lightbeams in the exact direction where they came from. Elegantly solved by cat eye reflectors:

[image: highway_reflectors]
[image: reflector]

Comment: No, it's not possible.  see comment at VK's answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a pile of broken mirrors will reflect uniformly all the time.

Comment: It should not reflect uniformly, it should reflect directed to the village

Comment: @SeverinSpörri it should be obvious that as the angle of the sun with respect to fixed objects on the ground (mirror,town) changes, the reflection angle has to change.    A corner-cube only works for retro-reflection, not  reflection to a specified angle.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need motors to track the sun and keep the beams directed where you want them.  Conceivably the motors could be solar powered.